# How to create a dataFame from a textfile in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a textfile in HDFS and the format is like:

`0029029070999991901010106004`+64333+023450FM-12+00001N9-`0078`1+381

`0035029070999991902010113004`+64333+023450FM-12+00001N9-`0100`1+381

What I trying to do is get the first 25 characters as string and the first 4 digit divide by 10 as double after the second 'minus sign' and skip all other characters like :

```
ID                                | Column
----------------------------      | ----
0029029070999991901010106004      | 007.8
0035029070999991902010113004      | 010.0
```

How I suppose to do this？Thanks all!

Comment: try some thing like this - ```df.withColumn("id",regexp_extract($"value","([0-9]{28})",0)).withColumn("column",regexp_extract($"value","N9-([0-9]{5})",1)).select("id","column").show(false)``` & you need to modify this as per your logic

Comment: +1 upvoted for your edit, please mention in your question 4 digits from left to right, else we will be considering from right to left & 0 are no value.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

May be your expected output is wrong.

`00781/10.0 =78.1` not `7.8`

`01001/10.0 = 100.1` not `10.0`

```
scala> val df = spark.read.text("/tmp/data")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0029029070999991901010106004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0202701N015919999999N0000001N9-00781+99999102001ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1381|
|0035029070999991902010113004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201401N011819999999N0000001N9-01001+99999100311ADDGF104991999999999999999999MW1381|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn("id",regexp_extract($"value","(^[0-9]{28})",0))
.withColumn("column",(regexp_extract($"value","N9-([0-9]{5})",1)/lit(10.0)).cast("double"))
.select("id","column")
.show(false)

+----------------------------+------+
|id                          |column|
+----------------------------+------+
|0029029070999991901010106004|78.1  |
|0035029070999991902010113004|100.1 |
+----------------------------+------+
```

**Updated** ignore above.

If you want only 4 digits you can try below code.

```
scala> df
.withColumn("id",regexp_extract($"value","(^[0-9]{28})",0))
.withColumn("column",(regexp_extract($"value","N9-([0-9]{4})",1)/lit(10.0)).cast("double"))
.select("id","column")
.show(false)

+----------------------------+------+
|id                          |column|
+----------------------------+------+
|0029029070999991901010106004|7.8   |
|0035029070999991902010113004|10.0  |
+----------------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much .But what I expected  is that four digiits after the second miuns sign instead of five. I've  just edit and highlighted the digits I want . But still ,thanks a lot!

Comment: updated answer, based on your edit. check and let me know if its not working..:)

Comment: I think something wrong when I create  df from a txt.... I created a case class 'Numbers' with id and column,then`val df=spark.sparkContext.textFile("data.txt").map(_.split("/t")).map(attributes=>Numbers(attributes(0))).toDF()` ,then when I run your code it saidIt said "cannot resolve 'value' given input columns :[id]"  ...

Comment: I have not used any case classes, just loaded your sample code as text file and used the above logic